# change directory is not working through script but working directly on machine

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

I am trying to run this command through script doing `ssh` and it is only executing `cd` command.

```
cd $(ls | tail -1)
```

While it is working directly on the machine.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Smells like an XY problem

Comment: Trying to enter a directory through a script

Comment: What are you doing with the changed directory? A working directory is only valid for a single process. When the process ends, the working directory is re-set. This applies to subshells too and to script executions. A script `#!/bin/sh cd directory` will not do what you expect when you run `./script.sh` you need to source it (`. script.sh`)

Answer (score 0):

I can just assume here, but are you quoting correctly? When you run `ssh user@host cd $(ls | tail -1)` the command substitution is performed on the client, not the server.

You have to use:

```sh
ssh user@host 'cd $(ls | tail -1)'
```

That mentioned, your command doesn't do anything. `cd` would change the working directory on the server and then the ssh session is terminated.

Comment: Hii, yes I am quoting correctly since I am doing ssh on multiple machines I already have them mentioned in a list >>>  ssh -n $file " pwd ; cd $(ls | tail -1) ;pwd"   .....this is how I am using it so seems no issue with ssh

Comment: Using `"…"` instead of `'…'` will still evaluate the command substitution on your local machine

Comment: I used one more cd command without $ just by simply adding a path cd abc/xyz it is working but not this one

Comment: Cd abc/xyz ;pwd ; cd $(ls |tail -1);pwd ... first pwd is giving correct result like abc/xyz but second is taking me back to home directry rather than takin inside the most bottom directry in xyz path

Comment: Are you sure? I just tried and it works, even with command substitution and pipes. It is essential to use single quotes `'…'` and not double quotes `"…"` because double quotes will still interpolate variables and substitute commands.

Comment: Yes it worked seems the issue somewhere lies with the $() bcs even in secon command when I input the last directory as I know what it is then it is working

Comment: `ssh knittl@server 'pwd ; cd $(echo abc | tr abc w | rev); pwd'` outputs `/home/knittl` and `/home/knittl/www` (as expected).  Does this match your expectations? Or do you expect something else to happen?